Using Tensorflow together with MRTK 3.0 in Unity Project for Android
I am looking for input in tackling this problem. I am pretty sure it should work using my approach but evidently it doesnt. I am trying to use MRTK, since I am also working with a Hololens 2 and I have the most experience with that Toolkit.
For now I am just trying to have it work without any extra features, so it is really just having the camera feed be displayed with some buttons to interact with, as well as the Tensorflow detection rectangles over the recognized objects. The buttons are just PoC that I can get MRTK to work in these circumstances.
Here are my assumptions:

The MRTK XR rig camera in Unity does not work as an input for Tensorflow-Lite.
I can add a second camera that works as an input feed for Tensorflow-Lite in Unity.

I have tried to do this and am unsure if my understanding of Unity and/or Tensorflow-Lite is the problem here, since I am a beginner. The current behaviour is that I can see the MRTK objects but other than that everything is black.
Is this fundamentally the wrong approach or have I just misconfigured the two cameras? Can it work but is not suggested as the solution would cause considerable resource drain down the line?
